# Forcing a chooser display in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have an application I want to be an alternative handler for outgoing calls.

It would make sense to have an IntentFilter to handle CALL or CALL_PRIVILEGED intents. But that's actually not the right way to do this as doing so can interfere with EMS/911 calls. According to Google, you should write a BroadcastReceiver that looks for a NEW_OUTGOING_CALL. See following link:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html

So I've done this, but I want the behavior to be the same as if their were multiple activities with IntentFilters to handle the processing for the outbound call, i.e., I want a Chooser to come up for the User to decide which App he wants to handle the Intent.

Writing this the "wrong" way, I get this functionality for free. How do I get it by going via the BroadcastReceiver route?